# How do I fix this Simple Styling Usercontrol with dependencyproperties on Title and Content?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a Silverlight XAML usercontrol that I want to use to show that elements are grouped  together in the layout. The xaml is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StylingLibrary.FieldSet"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignWidth="200" d:DesignHeight="200">

<Grid x:Name="FieldsetLayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource FieldsetBorder}">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="TheFieldsetContentPresenter" Content="{Binding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"/>
    </Border>
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource FieldsetTitleBackground}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="FieldsetTitleTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource FieldsetTitle}"/>
    </Border>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And its backing code contains mainly dependency properties:

```
public partial class FieldSet : UserControl
{
    public FieldSet()
    {
        TheFieldsetContentPresenter.DataContext = this;
        FieldsetTitleTextBlock.DataContext = this;
        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public String Title
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TitleProperty", typeof(String), typeof(FieldSet), null);

    public new FrameworkElement Content
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(MyContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ContentProperty", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(FieldSet), null);
}
```

Now whenever I try to use it like so:

```
<Styling:FieldSet Title="Projects">
       <TextBlock Text="test" />
</Styling:FieldSet>
```

Visual studio (2010) tells me that a NullReferenceException was thrown and it cannot create an instance of FieldSet. When trying to build and run the project, this is the error:

```
{System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The invocation of the constructor on type 'StylingLibrary.FieldSet' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. [Line: 81 Position: 44] ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at StylingLibrary.FieldSet..ctor()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
 at ProjectsOverview.Views.ProjectsList.InitializeComponent()
 at ProjectsOverview.Views.ProjectsList..ctor(ProjectsListViewModel m)}
```

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: After doing what Zabavsky suggested it works. 
The next problem is that I guess setting the datacontext of the Content on this usercontrol makes it impossible for other controls to put their datacontext in there. When I put an itemscontrol in it, the items are not set anymore.

Is there a way to fix that? (or should I create a new thread for this?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the constructor to

```cs
public FieldSet()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TheFieldsetContentPresenter.DataContext = this;
    FieldsetTitleTextBlock.DataContext = this;
}
```

First you need initialize the components, then you can set the `DataContext` to them.

Comment: Ok, this helps a lot, it now actually renders! But it brings up a new problem (see above)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create CustomControl and put use TemplateBinding rather than using Binding. Then you will be able to use this control from somewhere else and I will fix your issue.

[Template Binding and Custom control in Silverlight](http://www.exploresilverlight.com/2012/07/use-of-templatebinding-and-custom.html)

Cheers!
Vinod